# Partial git clone with relevant history

Tags: git

Let's say I've written a zillion puppet modules and I have their entire history within a single git repo, but now I really wished I had made one repo per module.  Divvying up the file structure is easy because each is wholly contained within their own directory and are organized like *GIT_ROOT*/modules/*NAME*.

Is there a way that I can divide this repo up and not loose the history for each module?  Ideally each repo would only have history relevant to the module it represents.  I tried cloning the entire thing and `git rm -rf` everything that's irrelevant but that retains irrelevant history.

I plan to glue them back together with git submodules, FWIW.

Comment: look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/62079208#62079208

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been playing with this a little bit, and it looks like the easiest way to split this up is using `git subtree split`:

> **split**
>
> Extract a new, synthetic project history from the history
>   of the  subtree. The new history includes only the
>   commits (including merges) that affected , and each
>   of those commits now has the contents of  at the
>   root of the project instead of in a subdirectory. Thus, the
>   newly created history is suitable for export as a separate
>   git repository.

So, for example, if I start with the [openstack-puppet-modules](https://github.com/redhat-openstack/openstack-puppet-modules) repository, which includes a bunch of individual puppet modules, I could split them up first into individual branches like this (I am only using eight modules here to keep things short):

```
for x in apache aviator ceilometer certmonger cinder common \
    concat firewall; do
  git subtree split -P $x -b split-$x
done
```

Once this is finished running, I have:

```
$ git branch | grep split-
split-apache
split-aviator
split-ceilometer
split-certmonger
split-cinder
split-common
split-concat
split-firewall
split-pacemaker
```

Each of those branches contains only the history for the specific
directory.  If I want to transform these into separate repositories, I
could do this:

```
for x in apache aviator ceilometer certmonger cinder common \
    concat firewall; do
  git init --bare ../repos/repo-$x
  git push ../repos/repo-$x split-$x:master
done
```

Now I have a collection of repositories:

```
$ ls ../repos/
repo-apache  repo-aviator  repo-ceilometer  repo-certmonger
repo-cinder  repo-common  repo-concat  repo-firewall  work-cinder
```

And I think we've achieved your goal.

Comment: Thank You!  That looks perfect for the job.  Bonus points for the excellent example.

Comment: This has worked very well for the big breakup.  Now I want to nuke each of those Puppet modules from the original Git repository so that I can bring them back in as Git submodules.  I read up on http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch and it would seem the following is perfect: `git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch modules/$NAME" HEAD`.  Indeed that removes it from the worktree, but the per-module history remains?  Is there a good way to nuke that too and retain the history for the leftovers?