# error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm facing this error when I try to clone a repository from GitLab (GitLab 6.6.2 4ef8369):

```
remote: Counting objects: 66352, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10417/10417), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The clone is then aborted. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

After few days, today I just resolved this problem. Generate ssh key, follow this article:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Declare it to

1. Git provider (GitLab what I am using, GitHub).
2. Add this to local identity.

Then clone by command:

```
git clone username@mydomain.com:my_group/my_repository.git
```

And no error happen.

**The above problem**

> error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data
>   remaining

because have error when clone by HTTP protocol (`curl` command).

And, you should increment buffer size:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Change from HTTP to SSH work for me. Config `http.postBuffer` didn't work.

Comment: if error is still there , you should edit your ssh config file vi /users/username/.ssh/config and add serverAliveInterval 120 and exit the vi using wq (to save and exit). This will actually prevent the server from timeout and connection break errors.

Comment: that's nice, but anyone knows why that happens for 100% cloned?

Comment: Changing ```http.postBuffer``` worked for me - thanks!

Comment: after all great steps listed here, `git clone ssh://git@github.com/<repository base>/<repository name>.git` is the only clone command that worked with me. and there's no need to reference the ssh is in the command at all (in case you're also wondering like i was).

Comment: worked for me too for pulling a large solution via a slow vpn connection

Comment: Beware: I experienced several issues with `npm publish` when raising the postBuffer. When I set it down to 50000000, issues were gone. The default value is 1000000, by the way.

Comment: changing http.postBuffer 524288000 worked for me.Thank you

Answer (score 367):

It happens more often than not, I am on a slow internet connection and I have to clone a decently huge git repository. The most common issue is that the connection closes and the whole clone is cancelled.

```
Cloning into 'large-repository'...
remote: Counting objects: 20248, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10204/10204), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

After a lot of trial and errors and a lot of “remote end hung up unexpectedly” I have a way that works for me. The idea is to do a shallow clone first and then update the repository with its history.

```
$ git clone http://github.com/large-repository --depth 1
$ cd large-repository
$ git fetch --unshallow
```

Comment: This is the only answer that describes a workaround for the problem without switching to SSH. This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: thx dude, this answer worked for me too. Just change my network with fast internet connection

Comment: The key here is `--depth 1` and `--unshallow`. This also works for fetching an existing repo on slow connection: `git fetch --depth 1` then `git fetch --unshallow`.

Comment: For clarity @AndrewT., the `git fetch --unshallow` command deals with loss of connection in a more forgiving way than the `git clone`?  And that's what makes the difference here?

Comment: Now, the `git fetch --unshallow` command give `RPC failed;` error

Comment: why turns out failure since 100% cloned, anyone knows the reason? thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. Failed on the `git fetch --unshallow`. Guess my repo is too big even for this approach. Only SSH worked.

Comment: If `git fetch --unshallow` still reports errors, you can use `git fetch --depth=100` and then `git fetch --depth=200` and then `git fetch --depth=300` and so on to fetch repo incrementally. This way works for Linux kernel repo, which is extremely large.

Comment: does `git fetch --unshallow` fetches all branches [as part of history info] ? I am still not seeing few branches. Am I missing something ?

Comment: as others mentioned, still can't get past `git clone` and my repo is just a jekyll site with some images. this answer is outdated, going with `ssh` and secure connections is the only real solution today.

Comment: Form me just using `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703069/2275206 did the trick

Comment: I tried this, but then all the files from the repo (in my case, SolidWorks files) are only 1KB large and cannot be opened. Git still says that they are up-to-date. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @haolee 's solution `git fetch --depth=100` and `git fetch --depth=200` worked for me. Below are the comments I ran.  `git clone http://github.com/large-repository --depth 1` and `cd large-repository` and `git fetch --depth=100`

Answer (score 50):

you need to turn off the compression:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

then you need to use shallow clone

```
git clone --depth=1 <url>
```

then most important step is to cd into your cloned project

```
cd <shallow cloned project dir>
```

now deopen the clone,step by step

```
git fetch --depth=N, with increasing N
```

eg.

```
git fetch --depth=4
```

then,

```
git fetch --depth=100
```

then,

```
git fetch --depth=500
```

you can choose how many steps you want by replacing this N,

and finally download all of the remaining revisions using,

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

upvote if it helps you :)

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me. On my case error was happening on:
git clone --depth=1 <url>
However, as per your instruction, I've executed first:
git config --global core.compression 0
Then all following steps, and everything worked great!
PS: I have good internet connection, just today is behaving weirdly. Thank you!

Comment: Can you detail what does disabling compression help accomplish?

Comment: @Slim Here what we are doing is disabling the default behavior of compressing the full object and then fetch. instead we are fetching without compressing which allows us to fetch step by step by specifying the depth.

Answer (score 24):

**When I tried cloning from the remote, got the same issue repeatedly:**

```
remote: Counting objects: 182, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (149/149), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

**Finally this worked for me:**

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/repositoryName.git --depth 1
```

Comment: what --depth 1 does

Comment: If the source repository is complete, convert a shallow repository to a complete one, removing all the limitations imposed by shallow repositories.

If the source repository is shallow, fetch as much as possible so that the current repository has the same history as the source repository.

Comment: BUT i don't want to `clone`, I want to `push` . How can i do it with depth

Answer (score 13):

Simple Solution: Rather then cloning via https, clone it via ssh.

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/vaibhavjain2/xxx.git - Avoid
git clone git@github.com:vaibhavjain2/xxx.git - Correct
```

Comment: Yes. I am windows user.

Answer (score 8):

Network connection problems.
Maybe due to the persistent connection timeout.
The best way is to change to another network.

Comment: Changed the wifi for a faster internet connection then it worked, thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 8):

### Usually it happen because of one of the below reasone:

1. **Slow Internet.**

- Switching to LAN cable with stable network connection helps in many cases. Avoid doing any parallel network intensive task while you are fetching.

2. **Small TCP/IP connection time out on Server side from where you are trying to fetch.**

- Not much you can do about. All you can do is request your System Admin or CI/CD Team responsible to increaseTCP/IP Timeout and wait.

3. **Heavy Load on Server.**

- Due to heavy server load during work hour downloading a large file can fail constantly.Leave your machine after starting download for night.

4. **Small HTTPS Buffer on Client machine.**

- Increasing buffer size for post and request might help but not guaranteed

> git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
>
> git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 524288000
>
> git config --global core.compression 0

Answer (score 6):

As above mentioned, first of all run your git command from bash adding the enhanced log directives in the beginning: `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git ...`

e.g. `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin`
This will show you detailed error information.

Answer (score 6):

These steps worked for me:using `git://` instead of `https://`

Comment: actually, this answer is more specific than next ones in this thread ..

Answer (score 4):

With me this problem occurred because the proxy configuration. I added the ip git server in the proxy exception.
The git server was local, but the no_proxy environment variable was not set correctly.

I used this command to identify the problem:

```
#Linux:
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

#Windows
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

In return there was the "Proxy-Authorization" as the git server was spot should not go through the proxy.
But the real problem was the size of the files defined by the proxy rules

Answer (score 4):

For me, the issue was that the connection closes before the whole clone complete. I used ethernet instead of wifi connection. Then it solves for me

Answer (score 4):

This error seems to happen more commonly with a slow, or troubled internet connection. I have connected with good internet speed then it is worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

For me what worked is, as this error may occur for memory requirement of git. I have added these lines to my global git configuration file  .gitconfig which is present in $USER_HOME i.e `C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\.gitconfig`

```
[core] 
packedGitLimit = 512m 
packedGitWindowSize = 512m 
[pack] 
deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
packSizeLimit = 2047m 
windowMemory = 2047m
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem arrive when you are proxy issue or slow network. You can go with the depth solution or

```
git fetch --all  or git clone
```

If this give error of **curl 56 Recv failure** then download the file via zip or
spicify the name of branch instead of **--all**

```
git fetch origin BranchName
```

Comment: Using `git fetch origin BranchName` I was able to continue an interrupted `git clone`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the answers on here.
I was trying to add cocoapods onto my machine.

I didn't have an SSH key so thanks @Do Nhu Vy

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703069/2481602

And finally used

```
git clone https://git.coding.net/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

to finally fix the issue found https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959034/2481602

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this problem also. resolve it.
The problem is the slow internet connection. Please check your internet connection nothing else.
I have connected with good internet speed then it is worked perfectly. hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs while cloning large repos. If `git clone http://github.com/large-repository --depth 1` does not work on windows cmd. Try running the command in windows powershell.

Answer (score 0):

can be two reason

1. Internet is slow (this was in my case)
2. buffer size is less,in this case you can run command
   git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved 100%. I was facing this problem , my project manager change the repo name but i was using old repo name.

```
Engineer@-Engi64 /g/xampp/htdocs/hospitality
$ git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repo/cms
Cloning into 'cms'...
remote: Counting objects: 10647, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

How i solved this problem. Repo link  was not valid so that's why i am facing this issue. Please check your repo link before cloning.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while pushing some code to Github.

I tried `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` but It didn't work for me.

**Reason**

It was because your **commit history and/or any file(s)** size is bigger.

**My Case**

In my case, package-lock.json was causing the problem.
It was **1500+KB** in size and **33K lines of code**.

**How I solved it?**

1. I commit and pushed everything **without package-lock.json**
2. **Copy** the content of **package-lock.json**.
3. **Created a new file** with the name of package-lock.json from the **GitHub repo page.**
4. **Paste** the content of package-lock.json **and commit.**
5. **git pull** on local.

And Done.

**Tips**

- Maintain each commit size smaller
- Push frequently
- Use a good internet connection

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --global core.compression 0
```

then

```
git clone --depth=1 <https://your_repo.git>
```

then

```
git fetch --depth=2
```

then

```
git fetch --depth=10
```

...
etc. until he writes

```
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

at the end you can write

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

and you will be thrown

```
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense
```

if at some stage you get an error again, try setting the **--depth** property to a smaller value and gradually increasing further

Comment: The same method is described in NikhilP's answer. Please do not post duplicate answeres.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when doing `git push` after [changing to HTTP/1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66014581/11829398).

Solution: turn off my VPN and re-run `git push`.

Answer (score -1):

Changing git clone protocol to try.

for example, this error happened when "git clone https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

you can try with "git clone git://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", maybe ok then.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to clone the repo with [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32444798)

Answer (score -2):

git config

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    compression = 0
[remote "origin"]
    proxy = 127.0.0.1:1086
[http]
    version = HTTP/1.1
[https]
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

retry.sh

```
set -x
while true
do
  git clone xxxxx
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

These steps are working for me:

```
cd [dir]
git init
git clone [your Repository Url]
```

I hope that works for you too.

Answer (score -16):

try this

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

this is work for me..
[capture.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY2qN.png)

Comment: The bug is sporadic due to an unreliable network. The solution presented here didn't actually fix the problem. The network just happened to be more reliable at the moment you tried cloning again.