# CocoaPods error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When I tried to import Realm with CocoaPods like this:

`pod install --verbose --no-repo-update`

then error happened:

`error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
     fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
     fatal: early EOF
     fatal: index-pack failed
     fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/ColinH/PEGTL' into submodule path '/private/var/folders/51/tzbm7yqs3bsck5vxz3xj5pkc0000gn/T/d20160925-2957-1pu1dou/Realm/ObjectStore/external/pegtl' failed`

why?

Answer (score 4):

The above error is mainly caused by the change of the security mechanism of os10.11+ and cocoapods1.0+ version upgrade. Mainly in the pod setup process. And the waiting time for this process is very long

```
git clone https://git.coding.net/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

The same effect as pod setup

Comment: Worked for me, referenced you in this question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57153959/2481602
Thanks Tim

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS 10.11, some cocoapods commands to change. If you have a pod setup or pod update problem, and it is difficult to solve, I suggest 10.11. Uninstall reinstall after installation of cocoapods has some different commands, the following summary:

1 check the ruby environment, if necessary, please update as follows

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```

2 uninstall cocoapods

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

3 reinstall cocoapods (Setup command has changed)

Before 10.11

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After 10.11

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoa pods
```

4

```
$ sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

//taking  CocoaPods Specs repository copy to your computer under directory  ~/.cocoapods

```
pod setup
```