# git clone from bitbucket error curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to clone a repo from bitbucket using a bash commandline with curl.

However, I get a curl 18 error. What should I do?

Comment: I haven't seen that error but it seems other did. [This question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining) look relevant.

Comment: yes I have seen it but I'm using bitbucket not github

Comment: github or bitbucket. It's similar issue. Too much data on repo and slow net might result in closing connection early.
 Simply, try again.

Comment: Can you show us the cURL request ? Just to make sure you're not doing anything crazy.

Comment: Anirudha it might be true I have installes smartgit cloned the repo the error showed but the next time it went well. I don,t know why but it miht be connection  this is my code  git clone https://amy_abdom@bitbucket.org/--------/shop.git  /hop