# Showing Permission denied on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 installed on Virtual box. I have installed LAMP and git successfully. I tried to clone my git repository using terminal but
it shows:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'directory-name': Permission denied
```

I tried to give directory permission using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html
```

but it is not working.

Comment: It seems that this is better posted on SuperUser or AskUbuntu rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it is not working". *What happens* when you run the `chmod` command?

Comment: When I run the command `chmod`, it says nothing. After run this 
command I again tried to clone my repository. The result was
same. Also I am not able to create directory. It throw the same message:
**Permission denied**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fresh install, so the owner of the `/var/www/html` folder is probably root ? If it is a development environment do the following commands as root, it will probably fix you permissions issue :

```
groupadd www-data
usermod -a -G www-data yourUsername
chown -R root:www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

Comment: When I run the following command:
`usermod -a -G www-data myUsername`
it shows the following message:
`usermod: Permission denied.`
`usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.`

Comment: It works. For this I need to run:
`sudo su`
Then the commands you suggest. Now I can clone my repositories from git though it gives the following error:
`error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

Comment: For the second comment, it's another issue you got here. Don't seem to be a permission issue with this output. Maybe you can find something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: got it. Thanks for your help.