# git - RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding data remaining - Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, git-push

I have seen few posts here regarding this but all of them while looking close to mine issue, are not the same.  They are eaither being reported on copying objectes, or reporting EOF error etc buy mine is reporting error while stating "Everyting up-to-date"

I am on MacBookPro and if I try to push my branch to origin, I get this

```
mymbp:EntriesMngrProj edwin$ git status
On branch 13552EntriesNew
nothing to commit, working tree clean
mymbp:EntriesMngrProj edwin$ git push origin 13552EntriesNew
Enumerating objects: 653, done.
Counting objects: 100% (530/530), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (359/359), done.
Writing objects: 100% (361/361), 85.64 KiB | 2.59 MiB/s, done.
Total 361 (delta 192), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Well, is everything up to date? There are many ways to check, here's one: `git fetch origin && git rev-list --oneline 13552EntriesNew ^origin/13552EntriesNew`. Is this an on-going problem or just happened once?

Comment: I typically commit changes to my current feature branch, switch to develop branch, do git fetch/merge (or pull) on develop, then switch back to my feature branch and do git merge there to merge develop to my feature branch.  So, I tried doing that of course first thing to make sure all is uptodate but discover that even though git status reports that there is nothing to commit, working tree is clean, attempt to checkout develop branch fails and complains about uncommitted files.  So, it looks like multiple issues here

Comment: Maybe you can view this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining)