# Rails 6.0 w/Webpacker: Heroku Push Fail: error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpacker

When pushing to Heroku, I'm encountering a timeout while compiling, as in the trace below:

```
...
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.12.3
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        yarn install v1.12.3
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning "@rails/webpacker > pnp-webpack-plugin > ts-pnp@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
remote:        warning " > rails-erb-loader@5.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 24.78s.
remote:        Compiling…
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: el remoto se colgó de manera inesperada
fatal: el remoto se colgó de manera inesperada
```

I've tried several times with same result.
I haven't changed anything that to my mind mey be causing this issue.

The last commited changes were mainly in JS files, and as it hangs while compiling, I guess it has something to do with JS assets.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I found some similarities on a possible solution for your case. I hope this helps

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after all I found the problem myself. It was an *import* of a file that had been removed. Webpacker wasn't throwing any errors, which had been hidding the issue.

Thanks!