# error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

Tags: git, push

> error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

I tried 'push' while writing 'git'.
However, the following message does not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: I got this error because I was trying `git push origin branch_name` and there was no remote branch corresponding to the local branch I'm trying to push.

Comment: Just try a better internet network.

Comment: Note: you can also get the almost same error message in completely different context. In my case, it was not related to git. The api response status code was 204, but there was data in response body which made content-length check fail.

Comment: I got this error on mac bcoz while cloning my laptop went to sleep?

Comment: I experienced this on an Inmarsat in-flight wifi connection. http.postBuffer solution worked for me.

Answer (score 240):

You can force git using http version 1.1

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

https://gist.github.com/daofresh/0a95772d582cafb202142ff7871da2fc

Comment: Why should one downgrade the HTTP version? eventually, we will be moving on to HTTP2.

Comment: This fixed the issue on MacOSX, `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` can not fix this issue. But @AbhishekSharma's question is good, why should we downgrade the HTTP version.

Comment: This version command fixed my issue. I tried the post buffer approach and also other options like adding user name in the git URL which didn't help me either.

Comment: In reply to questions about downgrading to HTTP/1.1, the error message posted by OP points to an issue with HTTP/2; it is likely that something beyond OP's control (a proxy, the GIT server, etc.) does not work well with HTTP/2. Until that's fixed, downgrading to HTTP/1.1 is a valid workaround.

Comment: Something else to mention: you may not want to include the `--global` flag, unless you always work with the same central server. If you work with multiple servers (e.g. GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, etc.), then you may want to set this config in a repo-by-repo basis.

Comment: I understand the resistance to downgrading HTTP as a solution, just like I understand why rolling back a software version seems like an awkward solution. However, after trying all kinds of other solutions, this one worked.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS even **without** the `--global` flag. Just typed: `git config  http.version HTTP/1.1` (This seemed to be a problem only with one specific remote I have.)

Comment: I cannot downvote this answer since it is obviously appropriate for many MacOS users. But is seems that the problem (and its answer) is OS-specific. For me for instance, this didn't work but  `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` did the trick in Ubuntu LTS 20, as other users have suggested. Perhaps it would be wise to edit this top-answer to mention its OS-specific aspect ?

Comment: can i do this with tortoise as well?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a 20GB+ repo to gitlab cloud, and it's resulting with a fatal pretty consistently after a large amount of time waiting. I've attempted this with `http.postBuffer` at 1GB. I'm going to give this a try and see what happens. I'll post back with whatever the results are.

Comment: I am using the Version Control tool in IntelliJ IDEA, but even if I use this command the push operation doesn't seem to work there. Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 135):

You might be pushing data larger than the postBuffer size.

You can try increasing post buffer size using

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

For reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reference but not working for me getting same error frequently.

Comment: If you have not set it globally, you will experience this in every git repo and config locally for every repo. Also check if you are uploading a really big file to the repo then the value of buffer size should be set accordingly

Comment: I tried with global as well as local but not working for me and actually I'm not uploading that much of big files also. I read reference provided by you.

Comment: It was nice reference and after reading and trying that I asked separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514449/git-error-rpc-failed-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly-protoco)

Comment: This solution was not worked for me and Also I have another doubt about switching HTTP version. You can refer my question there is one important answer too.

Comment: For future references, if the solution is not working you can find a possible explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517451/2650209)

Comment: Also tried this workaround and even got it suggested by github private support but it didn't work. Also 300MB weren't enough. What worked was to use a 1.7GB http.postBuffer instead of the 150MB which seem to be mentioned everywhere. Not a solution but at least a working workaround for my case. 
For the reference, i got the "RPC failed; curl" error in the middle of the upload at about 56%.

Comment: Whats so big that you need to upload on github :o Should use some cloud storage for that purpose I suppose.

Comment: Git is fine for huge amounts of data depending on how you use it. Also there's lfs. I like having submodules and everything in one place :)
In my case it's actually github enterprise but the underlying problem is the same.

Answer (score 112):

Simple solution (reverts to http 2 after) :

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
git push 
git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Comment: Why is recomended to return http/2?

Comment: @AntoCode, it's because it was originally in version http/2. Other pipelines that might be dependant on v2 might fail if the http version remains at 1.1

Comment: Why not just run `git config http.version HTTP/1.1` for that repository? That way you don't need to set it back to HTTP/2 afterwards. Since that change will only apply to the current git repository.

Comment: Nice idea @Xys. However, it's possible that `HTTP/2` is a default, not a set configuration name. This is the case when `git config --global http.version` returns nothing. In that case, the commands should be

`git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1; git push; git config --global --unset http.version`

A bash script that does the right thing in either case is left as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: I prefer config this on the working repo and not with the --global param.

Answer (score 62):

XCode 11.4.1

Increasing the git buffer size worked for me

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: whats the difference between using the --global tag and not?

Comment: `--global` tag makes it so that all git repositories you have will have a `postBuffer` of that amount. Omitting global means only that git repo will have a `postBuffer` of 524288000

Comment: this did it for me on raspberry pi over WLAN

Comment: this works when your internet is faster

Answer (score 50):

Working Solution:

First change HTTP version to 1.1 and then push and once done change back to HTTP2

```
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
After it push was ok and I have changed HTTP version to 2 again:
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Comment: This worked for me, but why? It's been fine with HTTP/2 for a number of years. Possible remote service down?

Answer (score 30):

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

This is the latest, should solve your issue

Comment: This is really a live saver, anytime anyday

Answer (score 26):

**I followed most of the answers but not solved my problem.**

**In my case, the answer is very simple**

I encountered this error when pushing GIT through an ADSL Broadband Wi-Fi network with low signal strength, low stability, and low speed.

Then,
I was able to push it very successfully when I pushed it into the GIT through a Fibre Broadband Wi-Fi network with greater signal strength, greater stability, and higher speed.

***Error:***

> **Push failed**
> Enumerating objects: 44, done. Delta compression using up to 12 threads RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) the remote end hung up unexpectedly Total 30 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0) the remote hung up unexpectedly

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful to people using search engines if you could post that error as ***text*** in your question instead of an image. Considering that this error is different than the one in the question, people getting this error might still arrive and find your answer helpful, but they can't do it if it's an image

Comment: Yeah same for me. I just changed the network connectivity to a faster one and the problem is solved!!

Comment: I also encountered this error:
"error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet"

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if that was the problem you could just retry it and it would have worked eventually.

Comment: This is what worked for me, which is annoying because it's not like the connection isn't there. git would reach the same point in the cloning each time and then fail out, despite the presence of a 300KB/S connection being available.

Comment: @SteveMoretz yes, you would think so, but it was the exact same situation for me. See my comment above.

Comment: Same here: While downloading something else, I could not clone git (twice), but it worked afterwards. This smells like a race condition, since TCP is reliable in other aspects than timing.

Answer (score 22):

It's was not working for me. But worked after downgrading version of `HTTP` from `2` to `1.1`:

```
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

After this change, pushing was successful and I have changed HTTP version to 2 again:

```
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Comment: it is also possible to make it not global but in project specific
git config http.version HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 6):

In most cases `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` should work.

In my case, I was pushing a large number of changes (I changed a lot of packages thus there were many lines updated) in my yarn.lock/package-lock.json file. Since it is usually not required, removing it made the error go away.
So you can try this too if you are working with Javascript

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like either the remote server you're using or some middlebox (e.g., a proxy) is not speaking the HTTP/2 protocol correctly.  You can either fix that by asking the owner of that remote server or middlebox to fix their server, or you can force the use of HTTP/1.1.

If you want to force the use of HTTP/1.1, you can set the `http.version` configuration option to `HTTP/1.1`.  That can also be set on a per-URL basis as described in the `http.<url>.*` section in the `git-config` manual page.

Comment: If a normal file has no 'push' error, if I 'push' the image file, an error occurs.

Comment: It may be that whatever network issue, remote server, or middlebox is there is causing problems with certain content, but this is definitely a network-related problem.

Comment: In my case the remote server is github.com. You would think they had their stuff together. I never had to change my http on my other repository. This one kept giving me 'fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly', but after  doing the change to http/2, my push succeeded.

Comment: GitHub supports both and both should work without problems (and do for millions of people a day).  It is likely that there is something else, such as a non-default antivirus or firewall, a proxy server, or TLS MITM device, all of which are known to cause problems with Git in general.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, increasing the buffer size will work.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

It worked for me.

Use of

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

should be kept as a last option.

Using a gitbash terminal on a windows machine (if this info helps you in any way).

Comment: I'm using WSL2 and this didn't help me...

Comment: Can you explain why? Both options should be temporary and reverted after resolution.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this if you have problems with your internet connection :

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000  # Set buffer size to 500 MB
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0      # Disable low speed limit
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999  # Set low speed time limit to a large value
```

Answer (score 4):

For my case with the bitbucket behind nginx, [disabling proxy request buffering](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-client-intended-to-send-too-large-chunked-body-779171802.html)  was the answer:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ...
    proxy_request_buffering off;

    # These are also relevant:
    proxy_read_timeout      600;
    client_max_body_size    0;
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to reset the origin to ssh instead of http/https:

```
git remote set-url origin git@your-git.com
```

To check your origins you can use:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 4):

My issue was slightly different, with a "packages already packed" info with the RPC::HTTP/2 stream not closed cleanly message.

For me this worked:

```
git checkout --orphan newBranch
git add -A  # Add all files and commit them
git commit -am "Clean Repo"
git branch -D master  # Deletes the master branch
git branch -m master  # Rename the current branch to master
git push -f origin master  # Force push master branch to github
```

Thanks to: https://panjeh.medium.com/cleaning-up-git-github-repository-without-deleting-git-directory-c86b7415b51b

Answer (score 4):

I went through a similar situation. I tried;

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1  
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

even,

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

[image: failed example]

but,  nothing changed. I had two folders with this error. one with 10MB size and one with 65MB.

finally.
**I tried with a Fibre connection.**

[image: worked proof]

So yeah. try with a different, higher speed connection. probably it will work.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

Using different internet access solved the problem for me, I switched from my main wifi and connect to my phone and it worked.

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by some block from the internet provider

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most popular answers is:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

**Don't do this blindly** as raising this is not, in general, an effective solution for most push problems, but can increase memory consumption significantly since the entire buffer is allocated even for small pushes(from the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).

Check if you've files with `size >100 MB` first. If yes, then there is a better-suited solution for your problem.

**Solution**: [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) as it is intended for versioning large files.

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio
> samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git,
> while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or
> GitHub Enterprise.

You can look at this good tutorial on [git-lfs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#) which will answer most of your follow-up questions.

Answer (score 3):

If none of this helps, maybe you could try using ssh to connect to your git repository. That helped me.

If you are using Bitbucket you can add your ssh key to the repository settings and that way you will gain ssh access.
On Github I think you should have ssh access by default. Try connecting to the repository using ssh instead of https, you can do that by changing the remote url for your git.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31680206)

Answer (score 3):

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
you can just increase your buffer size it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

With me there was issue with my internet and also the large amount of files in my code. I fixed this, Please check your internet speed and also use this.

```
   git config http.postBuffer 524288000
    git push
```

Answer (score 2):

for me helped just this

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ...
    location / {
         ...
         proxy_request_buffering off;
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, for me it turned out to be bad internet connection - I tried everything above, nothing worked, then I did a speed test and found I had 100+Mb download but only 0.x Mb upload at the time, due to some wifi issues. After I fixed it the problem disappeared.

Comment: Same here. I used a wi-fi repeater internet, checked the speed. Upload 0.07. Switched to ethernet and that  fixed the problem. Never thought git could fail with such errors because of the upload speed.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is just Change your internet network temporary for example use your mobile hotspot, and after you did push, you can be back to your current network.

This problem would be happened in pull, push or even clone commands. And the reasons could be your network setting related packet size setting, buffer size and ...

Answer (score 2):

You really might be pushing data having large size. I was having the same error then I preferred using git LFS and it worked.

Just untrack that specific file (file with huge size) before commit. Use following command.

```
git rm --cached "<file_name>
```

Then push remaining files and then use `git LFS` to upload the file with large size. To know how to upload using git LFS [refer this](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this. I just switched to another mobile hotspot and it worked for me .

Comment: not worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I solved this annoyng problem by changing my wi-fi DNS on my work laptop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This may not be the most information-packed answer in the world, but temporarily switching from my 5 GHz wi-fi network to my 2.4 network solved the problem and allowed me to move on with my life. Knowing /why/ is always better, but sometimes just knowing /how/ is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add an SSH key to your Github account. That was causing the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me I thought that was my internet so I tried with a better internet but the error persists. Until I have found this solution:

Basicaly I had to copy into another branch the files and delete the other and rename the current one. To clean the repo.

```
git checkout --orphan newBranch
git add -A  # Add all files and commit them
git commit -am "Clean Repo"
git branch -D master  # Deletes the master branch
git branch -m master  # Rename the current branch to master
git push -f origin master  # Force push master branch to github
```

Comment: The point is with this you will lose all previous commits from the branch master

Answer (score 1):

If you are **pushing large files** you might get this error just use [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to low signal strength. I have pushed heavy files in the open source repositories too and haven't encountered this error. More than the buffer size, it depends largely on the signal strength. You could try pushing it 2 or 3 times more or restart your router, and if it still doesn't work, try the following command:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
git push
```

Comment: I'm using WSL2 and this didn't help me...

Answer (score 1):

Could be caused by a folder/file having the same name with the branch.

Try:

```
git push <branch_name> --
```

If worked, then better rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by a forgotten `return 444;` in my nginx config. The connection termination caused this misleading error message under HTTP 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of some people here:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
git push
```

Results to an error:

```
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File public/img/layout/group-photo.psd is 184.91 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

So this is more of a file issue rather than a network connectivity issue in my case.
Move the large file out of the project and proceed to commit and push the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you maybe using a VPN,
I got the error while using VPN, I decided to turn my VPN off and try again,
then it Worked

Answer (score 0):

I live rurally and have mobile broadband, that is based on a very low 4g signal, I get two bars of signal on a good day. I was pushing several files amounting to only 39mb, which is well below github's max file size, I have also pushed much bigger commits on the same repo from this location, so it did not make sense that the file size caused the problems for me. I tried everything mentioned here, changing to HTTP1, and changing postbuffer did not help.

After several hours of head scratching, I restarted my router and was able to push the commit to github.

Hopefully this can help someone out there that also has terrible a internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Mobile Internet or Change the Internet Connection.
This is happened some time because of network issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32294723)

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by some block from the internet provider

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the approach but didn't work.

Turns out it was my network problem, just disconnect and then connect your wifi and it will work.

This is the error I was getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I didn't find any answers on this thread that mention simply retrying.  I ran into the same error, then simply retried my push and it worked fine. No changing settings or other actions needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider clearing/deleting the first git file from your file and the reinitalized it using the git init for th e second time, Then consider using a low speed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX59p.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was that upload speed on the landline internet was low (less than 1mbps) . So I used mobile hotspot and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this error.

```
error: 62928 bytes of body are still expected 663.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

On my case I solved it by using this command

```
git clone --depth 100000 git_repo
```

Increase it to 100000 and run it 5 to 6 times (it will decrease the bytes size each time)

Answer (score 0):

I received similar error while cloning one of the big project from gitlab environment. Happens due to unstable internet.
Here is what the error I got

```
...
...    
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream 
error: 7739 bytes of body are still expected 
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet 
fatal: error EOF 
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
$ git clone http://github.com/big-repo.git --depth 1
$ cd big-repo
$ git fetch --unshallow
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error while integrating stripe in ios using pods. I fixed by  this command.

> git config http.postBuffer 1024M

Don't use **--global**

Answer (score 0):

So this problem is basically a timeout thing. Your connection is simply too bad to get a response within 5 seconds or 10 seconds. Try this command (setting timeout to 1000sec):

```
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

If your error is related to trying to push large file (I had that error message in my case), run:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch {your full path file name}'
```

https://medium.com/@marcosantonocito/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272

Answer (score -1):

For me this query works :
`git push --set-upstream origin main`

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score -3):

The only issue in this case is Bad Internet Connection and nothing else. I fixed it by switching to better internet connection.
[image]

Answer (score -4):

Disconnect from your VPN and try again. That's what solved it for me.

Answer (score -6):

In my case, I changed my password on the server (Gitlab) but not in my local git credentials.