# problem with gitlab fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: gitlab

When I try to push a file to gitlab I get

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

$ Enumerating objects: 36, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly| 34.00 KiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 4.26 MiB | 152.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 36 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282476/error-rpc-failed-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly-protocol-erro Try forcing HTTP/1.1 or increasing the post buffer size.