# Pushing code to a non-existing branch in a repo

Tags: git, github

Cloning a repo and creating a branch on my local repo `$ git checkout -b jovick-coder`,
I made changes and added `$ git add`.
I made a commit `$ git commit -m "first commit"`.
This branch is not created remotely.
First how will I push my code to the existing branch `jovick-coder`.

I used
`$ git push` and I got:

> fatal: The current branch jovick-coder has no upstream branch.
>
> > To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
> > `git push --set-upstream origin jovick-coder`

was suggested to me and I tried it. This is what I got then:

> Enumerating objects: 23, done. Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads Compressing objects: 100%
> (22/22), done. error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not
> closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) Wsend-pack: unexpected disconnect while
> reading sideband packet Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 6.14 MiB |
> 99.00 KiB/s, done. Total 22 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date

please I need this help I am stuck

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no changes on the remote repo"? Where did you look?

Comment: sorry it was not successful

Comment: Can you try it again? It looks like an issue because of the internet connection.

Comment: I have tried over and over again still yet the same message

Comment: This seems to be a defect of the server, there is nothing you can do to fix this via git comands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL\_ERROR (err 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282476/error-rpc-failed-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly-protocol-erro)

Answer (score -1):

your git commands seems like correct

but as your question title says "Pushing code to a non-existing branch in a repo", answer for that is:

suppose your current local branch is "dev" then

> git push origin dev:jovick-coder

it will create a new branch at remote if not exist else update if exists.