# How do i fix this error "error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)"

Tags: git, github

I have a repository that i want it to be pushed to github.
Of course, i have done:

- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m '...'
- git remote add ...

After all this is done, i finally run the git push command, i.e

```
git push -u origin main
```

When I try to push to my github repository, I get this error, which is very cryptic for me to understand
[image: Error msg from git push command]

**Note**: I have git lfs in my project tracking all jpg images. I ran this command: `git lfs track "*.jpg"` hoping it would solve. But even before using `git lfs` i still ran into the same error.

**What i have tried**

I have tried running the command below obtained from this [source](https://gist.github.com/daofresh/0a95772d582cafb202142ff7871da2fc) but i am still unsuccessful.

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

I have also tried to delete git tracking from my project(`rm -rf .git`) and re-initialize git again(`git init`).

what could be the problem, since i have searched resources on the internet and i seemingly can't find the solution.

Comment: Clearly related (though the "err" number is different): [error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59282476/1256452). I would bet this is a real duplicate, with the same real solution: fix the proxy that's corrupting your data stream. Using ssh as a workaround *may* work.

Comment: This is probably a problem with some sort of proxy, whether that's a normal proxy, a TLS middlebox, or a non-default antivirus or firewall.  You should never see this error in normal operation.

Comment: i do have other git repositories that work fine, but when i come to this specific project, it misbehaves. I didn't configure any proxy and i am using the same computer which is working for other git repos

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.