# Cant upload the content to my existing git repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github

Tried to upload my **react** file to a GitHub repository. I have committed all of my files, I'm sure of that. This is the error im getting:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\brown-react\brown> git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 52, done.
Counting objects: 100% (52/52), done.  
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 14.06 MiB | 221.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Commit command result:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\brown-react\brown> git commit
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\brown-react\brown>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Try increasing the buffer size

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html

**Solution 2:**

Downgrade and upgrade HTTP version as suggested here:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66014581/5898385

Comment: @Anurag did you try to reinstall git and see if it works? Also try with another network.

Answer (score 0):

Try

- `git remote rm origin` then
- `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git` (replace username with your username and project with your project name)

Check out this answer for further reference [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)