# error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

Tags: git, github, fatal-error

This error (**fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly**) keeps popping up when I tried to push my work to GitHub. 
Tried all the solutions mentioned in the articles; [error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282476/error-rpc-failed-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly-protocol-erro)
Few to mention

- `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
- `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`

  Help me out here..

Comment: You won't see this problem if you're using HTTP 1.1.  What error message do you get when you set `http.version` to `HTTP/1.1`?  Also, please [see the Git FAQ}(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) about why you should not set or need to set `http.postBuffer`.

Comment: Downsizing to HTTP 1.1 is almost never a good idea, we should go forward instead of backwards. It's best to look for different solutions first IMHO.

Comment: Yes. I slightly have some idea that downsizing HTTP version is not good. I did it because I had no other option. To answer both questions, the error I get is the same in spite of HTTP version.

Comment: Currently have the same problem, it only happens when a filesize is > 400kb, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, although I never had this before.

Your post buffer setting might be a bit overkill. Try to use a value like:

```sh
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
# and then
git push
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But the problem still is the same no matter what

Comment: Sorry to hear this. What is your git provider? GitHub or something else?

Comment: Yes it is GitHub

Answer (score 0):

upgrading your git version may also help