# Can someone help me push code to my github repo?

Tags: git, github

I get hit with this error anytime I try to push code to my github repo

```
Enumerating objects: 104, done.
Counting objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (104/104), 2.77 MiB | 55.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 104 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0       
fatal: the remote end hun
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of one of the many cases covered by [bk2204's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295648/1256452). Lots of "security" boxes break http.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

`first:-`

downgrade your version of http from 2 to 1.1 using this command

```
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

`second:-`
then push the code using

```
$ git push
```

`third:-`
then again change the version of http to 2.

```
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use Github Desktop to push and pull your code to Github

https://desktop.github.com/

For more info read their docs

https://docs.github.com/en/desktop

This is an option