# git closed unexpectedly when I wrote git push

Tags: git, github, fatal-error

I have a folder named NeuralNetwork-numpy.

Commands I wrote:

```
NeuralNetwork-numpy> git add .
warning: in the working copy of 'data/fashion-mnist_train.csv', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'stracth-NN.ipynb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

NeuralNetwork-numpy> git commit -m "files added"
[githubtuna 52b7571] files added
 7 files changed, 70339 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 data/fashion-mnist_test.csv
 create mode 100644 data/fashion-mnist_train.csv
 create mode 100644 data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
 create mode 100644 data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
 create mode 100644 data/train-images-idx3-ubyte
 create mode 100644 data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte
 create mode 100644 stracth-NN.ipynb

NeuralNetwork-numpy> git push
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 67.23 MiB | 2.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried delete folder and recreate with this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/vahsi-bozkirli/NeuralNetwork-numpy.git
```

but nothings change

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how large the files you are trying to push are, but browsing the Internet I can see the `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` error may happen if you are trying to push large objects. As I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851500/11961036), it should be enough to send this command:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Instead, the `error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)` error happens because git is using the wrong protocol. As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474908/11961036), it should get fixed with:

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```