Cloning a git repository: Fatal errors and stops
I am using a Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 24)
// To install fabric samples and binaries
./install-fabric.sh docker samples binary

I am having a Git issue when trying to clone a repository. I am unable to solve it even after trying different compression params change.
===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 13369, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (252/252), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (157/157), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 38022 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fabric-samples v2.5.7 does not exist, defaulting to main. fabric-samples main branch is intended to work with recent versions of fabric.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git


This might be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282476/error-rpc-failed-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly-protocol-erro

Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

You may add some details about your git config and your network config
