# Git clone --depth=1 on large remote repo won't work

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

I just started to work on a project that have a lot of unnecessary big binary file. The project is a Unity game well over 150MB and no lfs and gitignore present so far and there is already 20+ commits with important gameplay features on the repo. I tried `git clone --depth=1 remote_address` and git is only able to receive 3% of the object before throwing `error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

I finally managed to solved it by doing the followings:

I added `--filter=blob:size=10mb` when clone the repository

and then with a `git checkout *`

and finally a `git pull`

which managed to clone the project partially.

But the problem is that I have to regenerate a lot of packages like Library, Project setting etc. Which will cause a merge conflict with the rest of the team if they pull my changes down.

I'd like to solve this better by being able to pull everything from the remote in steps and then do some cleaning to avoid conflict. Anyone has any ideas how to improve? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151771/9073437

Comment: You *really* don't want the Library directory checked into source control. It is meant to be generated on each machine. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for the explanation!