# When i use "git push heroku master" in django 3 I get a fatal error and "heroku open" I get an "Application error"

Tags: fatal-error, git-push, heroku-cli, django-3.0

```
PS C:\Users\reddy\redcloud> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 386 bytes | 48.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: I am new to web development and this is my first app.

Comment: your error is not about git : `Installing SQLite3 error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` is your connection stable?

Comment: [maybe the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining)

Comment: Yes, my connection is stable...

Comment: I tried the above solution, it did not work