# Remote hang up when I push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to push my project to GitHub. I have done:

```
$ git init
$ git add.
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
$ git branch -M main
```

Everything is fine, but when I push my project to github I get this:

```
$ git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 649, done.
Counting objects: 100% (649/649), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (634/634), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly | 54.00 KiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (649/649), 45.18 MiB | 795.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 649 (delta 134), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `https://github_username/` looks wrong.  Did you mean `https://github.com/username/`?

Comment: Did you try using SSH instead of HTTPS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining)

Comment: @matt no brother. that answer hasn't helped me

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)