# cant push changes to git

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to push changes to git, but it fails everytime giving error

```
 $ git push
Enumerating objects: 57, done.
Counting objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 23.07 MiB | 30.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 44 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I use these commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'upgrade'
git push
```

I tried:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

but it hasn't worked too.
What should I do now?

Comment: What's your remote look like? What exact command are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I using `git init`, `git add .` , `git commit -m 'upgrade'`, `git push` commands. Before I was pushing changes without any problem.

Comment: Please update the question. Add the ouput of `git remote -v`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I never use `git remote -v`

Comment: @Myrat. Why not?, and can you please [edit] your question with the additional information?

Comment: @MadPhysicist after which command should I use it?

Comment: Any time. It just lists your remotes