# Unable to clone bitbucket repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I was trying to clone bitbucket repo but I get very weird error saying
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

I tried to clone with --depth 1 but no luck, also tried with increasing buffer size in .gitconfig
Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining)

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: <br/> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: None of the above posts works for me, I tried all of them.