# how to get files from shallow-then-unshallowed git clone?

Tags: git, blob, shallow-clone

In order to [clone a really large repository via a slow internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151771/5333340), I did this:

```
$ git clone http://.../large-repository --depth 1
$ cd large-repository
$ git fetch --unshallow
```

But then, all binary files (in my case, SolidWorks files) have only 1KB size or less and look like this if opened in a text editor:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:14fe843075b881f8baaede83c14cbf0024fe5eda4583c0d87d906a4bfc66da1f
size 419328
```

If I do `git checkout`, git tells me that everything is up-to-date.

**How do I make git download the actual files?**

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when said files are actually managed by [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.com/).

You need to install `git-lfs` on your own workstation: follow this procedure:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage

From within your repo, you will then need to run `git lfs fetch` to download the actual files from whatever storage server is configured for that repository.