GIT - error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining when clone Supabase
I want to setup Supabase for Self-Hosting with Docker. But I failed when clone supabase github.
PS C:\AaFolder\Dev\Supabase> git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/supabase/supabase
Cloning into 'supabase'... 
remote: Enumerating objects: 10901, done. 
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10901/10901), done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9365/9365), done. 
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining 
error: 3792 bytes of body are still expected 
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet 
fatal: early EOF 
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

This is what I have already done:
Increased the git buffer size:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
Tried to use SSH:
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:supabase/supabase.git
Adjusted Git configuration for HTTP/2:
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
None of these worked. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Large commit; took me a few minutes to clone even on my very good network; after cloning just 1 commit I got 800M in .git and 900M in the working tree, wow. Also try this: git config --global core.compression 0; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079208/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+RPC+failed%3B+curl+18+transfer+closed+with+outstanding+read+data+remaining

@phd Wowza. They should warn about that in the readme.
